# Who first wrote down $S^6$'s standard almost complex structure? And who first proved that it is not integrable?

Tags: mathematics, differential-geometry

It is well known that $S^6$ admits an almost complex structure, inherited from its manifestation as the space of unit imaginary octonions. This almost complex structure is also well-known not to be integrable, i.e. not derived from a genuine complex structure.

Both of these facts were known by the early 50's, as mentioned e.g. in [the introduction to this paper by Calabi](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=130698), which contains references (numbers 8 and 23 for its existence and numbers 7, 9 for non-integrability).

I suspect that the existence might have been known for some decades by that time, since it already appeared in a textbook (the above-mentioned reference 23) and is a relatively easy linear algebra-type result. Perhaps Cartan wrote it down already?

Regarding non-integrability, I suspect (for no particularly strong reasons) that it was only discovered around 1950 (the references Calabi gives are from 1951), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this arxiv paper by Atiyah](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.09366.pdf), existence and construction dates from 1947; non-integrability from 1951.

Here is Atiyah's history:

Ehresmann 1947: Introduced the notion of almost complex structure
and showed that the 6-sphere admits an almost complex structure, but
explicitly points out that he does not know whether it has a complex
structure.

Hopf 1947: Proved that $S^4$ and $S^8$ do not admit almost complex structures.

Kirchhoff 1947: Uses octonions to construct an explicit almost complex
structure on $S^6$.

Eckmann-Frohlicher and Ehresmann-Liberman 1951: Independently
prove that Kirchhoff’s almost complex structure on $S^6$ is not integrable
to a complex structure.

Borel and Serre 1953: Prove that $S^{2n}$ admits an almost complex structure
if and only if $n = 1$ or $3$.

Hirzebruch 1954 and Liberman 1955: Remarks that it is still not known
whether $S^6$ has a complex structure.

---

**EDIT**

Regarding your request for sources, here are my “mixed results”.

Ehresmann’s 1947 introductory results can be found here : [Ehresmann, C., Sur la theorie des espaces fibres, Colloque de Topologie Algebrique, C.N.R.S., Paris (1947), pp. 3.](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1950.2/Main/icm1950.2.0412.0419.ocr.pdf)

Borel and Serre’s non-existence result for even dimensional spheres can be found here : [A. Borel, J.P. Serre *Groupes de Lie et puissances réduites de Steenrod* Amer. J. Math., 75 (1953), pp. 409-448](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/borelserre.pdf)

For Hopf’s 1947 result, I cannot locate the original paper, however the source is identified in [Robert Green and Shing-Tung Yau’s *Differential Geometry*](https://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=AGQECAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA99&dq=Hopf%201947%20almost%20complex&ots=DY6RLOJbpu&sig=sCcEhkZ3v9JVFC12NR6dEVGQQwU&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Hopf%201947%20almost%20complex&f=false) 
 as H. Hopf, Sur les champs d’element de surface dans les varietes a 4 dimensions, Topologie Algebrique, Paris 1947, Editions CNRS.

The original paper giving Kirchhoff's construction is not easy to locate.  Possibly from A. KIRCHHOFF, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris vol. 225 (1947).

I am not able to source the non-integrable to a complex structure result.

Comment: On the recent status of whether $S^6$ has a complex structure see [Is there a complex structure on the 6-sphere?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1973/is-there-a-complex-structure-on-the-6-sphere) and [Complex structure on $S^6$ gets published in Journ. Math. Phys on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210089/complex-structure-on-s6-gets-published-in-journ-math-phys). Lots of controversy on whether or not it has been solved with some prominent mathematicians (like Atiyah) offering proofs that apparently turned out to be incorrect.

Comment: @Conifold It is comforting to know that even mathematicians of Atiyah's quality can get it wrong.The most fiendishly difficult questions should result in the juiciest controversies - possibly because so few people are in a position to fully understand the material.